# Creating a Windows Service using VS Community Edition and Windows 10 Home

Tags: c#, windows, dll, service

I've looked at many posts regarding this issue and maybe I have not been able to connect the dots but I would like to create a Windows Service using Visual Studio C# Community Edition. When I try to create a new project `Service.dll` required for `System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase` does not exist.  I would like to create a service directly instead of writing a Java app and using a thirdparty tool to convert it.

What exactly do I need for this library?

Comment: What is "service.dll"? That's not where that namespace lives.  What is the exact error/symptoms when you try to create a Windows Service project?

Comment: Sorry, not a Windows developer.  I really don't get any errors.  I simply try creating a new Project, try to search for the resource "System" (which nothing comes up) so I get a bunch of non-compilable code.